# check for matching key value in multidimensional array if exists in new array update key value by adding the the number

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

So I have an array that has multiple entries based on the same order (soId). what I need to do is combine the totals of all the orders that have the same soId into a new array.  Here is an example of my array:

```
    array:3738 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "A" => "1/3/2021"
    "B" => 10556
    "C" => 6963
    "E" => "AMAZON - D"
    "K" => "0.00"
    "L" => "15.00"
    "M" => "-15.00"
    "Q" => "111-327***"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "A" => "1/3/2021"
    "B" => 10556
    "C" => 6963
    "E" => "AMAZON - D"
    "K" => "218.98"
    "L" => "47.06"
    "M" => "171.92"
    "Q" => "111-327***"
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    "A" => "1/3/2021"
    "soId" => 10556
    "C" => 6963
    "E" => "AMAZON - D"
    "K" => "0.00"
    "L" => "6.99"
    "M" => "-6.99"
    "Q" => "111-32707***"
  ]
  3 => array:8 [▼
    "A" => "1/3/2021"
    "B" => 10556
    "C" => 6963
    "E" => "AMAZON - D"
    "K" => "0.00"
    "L" => "25.00"
    "M" => "-25.00"
    "Q" => "111-3270792-5031461"
  ]
```

So that the matching soID rows would be combined in the new array and would look like this:

```
array:3738 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "invoice" => "1/3/2021"
    "soId" => 10556
    "invoiceId" => 6963
    "client" => "AMAZON - D"
    "salePrice" => "218.98"
    "unitCost" => "94.05"
    "margin" => "124.93"
    "extInvoice" => "111-327***"
  ]
```

Here is what I was trying but I cannot seem to detect the soId in the new array.

```
$sheetData = array();

foreach ($sheet as $row) {
            //check for matching key value in multidimensional array
            if (isset($sheetData['soId'])) { // This is not working skips to else
                  // This occurence found in the new array
                 // add+ the salePrice to the new array salePrice.
                // add+ the unitCost to the new array unitCost.
               // add+ the margin to the new array margin.


                }
                else {

                // first occurence of soId
                $sheetData[] = array(
                    'invoice' => $row['A'],
                    'soId' => $row['B'],
                    'invoiceId' => $row['C'],
                    'client' => $row['E'],
                    'salePrice' => $row['K'],
                    'unitCost' => $row['L'],
                    'margin' => $row['M'],
                    'extInvoice' => $row['Q']
                );

            }


        }
```

I am not sure how to accomplish both identifying the multiple occurrences of the soId in the new array (sheetData) or how I could if found combine the total of the three rows: salePrice, unitCost, and margin on the matching soId rom in the new array.

Comment: Can there be multiple differening soIds in the `$sheet` array?

Comment: yes. there will be multiple soId's with 1 or many entries. @Remy

Comment: I won't know the soId until we loop through the $sheet array. For every occurrence of the same soId I need to combine the three matching numbers into a new row in the new array.

Comment: Also, is there any significance in the letters in your loop? Since the fields in the dd you provided seem to differ.

Comment: @Remy in the first original array $sheet the key is A,B,C,D,E,F,G etc.. the new array I named them so my Original array example should have showed the correct ABCD Keys. I will try to edit this.

Comment: Does it matter which `extInvoice` is kept?

Comment: @AbraCadaver That is in the new array  Key Q from $sheet the original array.

Comment: @Remy Refresh the page and you will see I updated the array to show Original array and then how the new array looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the conditional statement evaluating to false has to do with the fact that you simply push a new array into `$sheetData`.

`$sheetData` looks something like the following in the process:

```
$sheetData = [
    0 => [
        'invoice' => 'some_value',
        'soId' => '1234',
        ....
    ]
];
```

Thus whenever the test for `isset($sheetData['soId'])` is evaluated, it evaluates to false. Because `'soId'` is not directly set on `$sheetData` but on one of the nested arrays (in the example index 0).

So, what I personally would do or recommend is to create a small mapping. This mapping will be used to relate the unique identifier soId to an array index.
Whenever we first encounter a new soId we will thus push it onto the result array, followed by mapping the soId to its index.

This allows us to access the array index in constant time and to update the respective sums as such.

Please see the following example:

```
$map = [];
$sheetData = [];

foreach ($sheet as $row) {
    $soId = $row['B'];

    // Since there seemed to be presence of thousand separated numbers
    // we remove the separation symbol and convert it to a floatval first.
    $salePrice = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $row['K']));
    $unitCost = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $row['L']));
    $margin = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $row['M']));

    if (!key_exists($soId, $map)) {
        // For simplicity let's rename the fields the first
        // time we encounter the soId.
        $row = array(
            'invoice' => $row['A'],
            'soId' => $soId,
            'invoiceId' => $row['C'],
            'client' => $row['E'],
            'salePrice' => $salePrice,
            'unitCost' => $unitCost,
            'margin' => $margin,
            'extInvoice' => $row['Q']
        );

        // Array push gives us back the number of items,
        // hence - 1 is the index in the result array.
        $index = array_push($sheetData, $row) - 1;
        // For constant time access we track where we
        // stored the soId in the sheetData array.
        $map[$soId] = $index;

        continue;
    }

    // Otherwise we just add the values to the running totals.
    $sheetData[$map[$soId]]['salePrice'] += $salePrice;
    $sheetData[$map[$soId]]['unitCost'] += $unitCost;
    $sheetData[$map[$soId]]['margin'] += $margin;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sheetData);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [invoice] => 1/3/2021
            [soId] => 10556
            [invoiceId] => 6963
            [client] => AMAZON - D
            [salePrice] => 218.98
            [unitCost] => 94.05
            [margin] => 124.93
            [extInvoice] => 111-327***
        )
)
```

Comment: Wow. OK tht was well written. I replace mu code with your example code and received this error on this line:
` $sheetData[$map[$soId]]['unitCost'] += $row['L'];

`
error: ErrorException
A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Could you try and take a look at the value that caused that?

Comment: it seems to be the adding the values to the running totals is causing that error.

Comment: I commented out each line one at a time and the error followed each of the three lines.

Comment: There might be some data inconsistency in what I presume is column L that causes this behaviour?

Comment: Sometimes Column K could be 0.00  and the Margin can be a negative ie -6.99
L will always be a full amount ie 34.99

Comment: Could there be separation symbols? Those are things you might need to clean up a bit, since addition should work on 0 values and negative values.

Comment: I have dumped the array $sheet can I add a code share for you to see the entire array?

Comment: Yes, if it's a long dd maybe it's better to use something like pastebin and I can take a look. (Not 100% sure if I'll quickly find out the value it breaks on)

Comment: snipper.io/s/-MShdnrP8gIVPvErOhr3

Comment: I see, there are some thousand separation symbols in there as `1,234`

Comment: @JasonBrashear I believe it should suffice as is.

Comment: So strange that it does not work but with that error. Is it possible that it is looking at this as a string and not an intager?

Comment: Did you see the update? If it still doesn't work, what is the error?

Comment: Oh! I see it and YES!!!!! That worked!!!!! Thank you @Remy! Thank you so so much!!

Comment: @JasonBrashear no problem, also please don't forget to mark your question as answered if that did it for you!

Comment: Done deal. Thank you agan!

Answer (score 0):

Create your result indexed on the `soId` (index `B`) and add the subsequent ones:

```
foreach($sheet as $row) {
    if(!isset($result[$row['B']])) {
        $result[$row['B']] = array(
                'invoice' => $row['A'],
                'soId' => $row['B'],
                'invoiceId' => $row['C'],
                'client' => $row['E'],
                'salePrice' => $row['K'],
                'unitCost' => $row['L'],
                'margin' => $row['M'],
                'extInvoice' => $row['Q']);
    } else {
        $result[$row['B']]['salePrice'] += $row['K'];
        $result[$row['B']]['unitCost']  += $row['L'];
        $result[$row['B']]['margin']    += $row['M'];
    }
}
```

Not necessary but if you want to re-index it then:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: This gave an error: A non well formed numeric value encountered
When it got to  $result[$row['B']]['unitCost']  += $row['L'];

Comment: here is the Full Origina $sheet array: https://snipper.io/s/-MShdnrP8gIVPvErOhr3

Comment: Then one of those values is not numeric https://3v4l.org/8C91i.